# cramer's rule for a linear equation - zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am new to cramer's rule and I want to ask what happens if the first determinant is zero(the matrix with the initial coefficients).... or some of the other determinants is zero.(when you already start calculating Det(X),Det(Y) etc...)

Comment: If you get a zero determinant for a matrix, then the matrix is called singular, and you cannot solve for the system's unknowns. Cramer's rule follows this, by showing there is no solution for the unknowns with a zero determinant. If $Det(x) = 0$, then $x = 0$ by the rule.

Comment: @Kaynex can I get some reference?(good site to read from)